# grafana master detail dashboard

Tags: influxdb, grafana

I am using Grafana to display data from InfluxDB datasource. I am confused, is there way send "unique id" or another string parameter between dashboards in Grafana? It means when we click on any element on one dashboard, keep parameter of clicked item and go to another dashboard, where we can insert parameter from previous dashboard to query on new dashboard?
current dashboard -> click -> saved item parameter -> go to new dashboard -> use saved parameter to create query for new dashboard  ?

I was looking similar solution on http://docs.grafana.org/ , http://play.grafana.org/ and other sites but didn't find the answer

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried Drilldown/detail link?

Drilldown / detail link
The drilldown section allows adding dynamic links to the panel that can link to other dashboards or URLs

Each link has a title, a type and params. A link can be either a `dashboard` or `absolute` links. If it is a `dashboard` links, the dashboard value must be the name of a dashboard. If it's an `absolute` link, the URL is the URL to link.

`params` allows adding additional URL params to the links. The format is the `name=value` with multiple params separate by `&`. Template variables can be added as values using `$myvar`.

When linking to another dashboard that uses template variables, you can use `var-myvar=value` to populate the template variable to a desired value from the link.

[Link to docs page](http://docs.grafana.org/reference/graph/)